# Trying to figure out why this if statement wouldn't work

Tags: python, if-statement

I feel like it's probably redundant with the two `with` statements, I wanted to add the `if/else` incase it didn't write the file for some reason it would notify me. How would I get `this == "what is written in the file"`

```
print("\tThis script is to erase and rewrite files")
filename = input("Filename: ")

print(f"\tWe're going to erase {filename}, then rewrite it.\n")
input("To cancel press CTRL-C\nTo continue press RETURN")

with open(filename, "w") as target:
  print("Opening the file...")
  print("Erasing the file. Goodbye!\n")
  target.truncate()
  rewrite = input("Time to rewrite your file, when you're finished   press RETURN:\n ")
   target.write(rewrite)

print("\n\tRewrite Confirmation:\n")
with open(filename) as this:
   print('> ', this.read(), '\n')
   if this == rewrite:
      print("Rewrite complete.")
   else:
      print("Rewrite failed. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Do you know what `this == rewrite` is doing?

Comment: Why are you expecting a text string to equal a file object?

Comment: You are comparing a file handle to a string. This has to fail.

Comment: I thought i could get that to equal what is in rewrite. As in like "rewrite = xxxx"

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in a Python debugger and look at your variable values as you step through it. Pay particular attention when you get to the `if` statement. There are several good Python debuggers you could use. What operating system are you on, and what editor are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using Atom on Mac. Im pretty new at this.Is there anyway I could get this == to whatever was written in the file?

Comment: You might try the [Atom Python debugger](https://atom.io/packages/python-debugger). I don't have any experience with it personally. If you install Python it includes an IDE with integrated debugger called IDLE, so you could also use this to debug your code. I haven't used IDLE on the Mac either, but if you search for "python idle mac" you should find some tips. Either way, a good debugger is worth its weight in gold when you're learning a new language.

Comment: You should save the string from `this.read()` so you can print it and then compare it to the `rewrite` string.

Comment: Side-note: Running `truncate` on a file you *just* opened in mode `"w"` is pointless: mode `"w"` is *defined* to open the file for write and truncate it to zero bytes, so the `truncate` call is redundant before you've written anything to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on saving that string to compare the two?